# MassTransit - GetSendEndpoint for using In Memory

Tags: masstransit

I am beginning with MassTransit, for a publisher/consumer scenario. In production we will be using SQS, however i would like to be able to use "In Memory" for development locally.

I am having trouble with forming the correct Uri for the call to ISendEndpointProvider.GetSendEnpoint(), as per:

```
//THE SET UP CODE:
x.AddConsumer<MTConsumer, MTMessageConsumerDefinition>()
    .Endpoint(e =>
    {
        // override the default endpoint name
        e.Name = "process-input-item";
        //... more configurations as per docs here...
    })
    ;
    x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});


//The Publish Code:  
  var endpoint = await SendEndpointProvider.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("/ProcessInputItem"));
  await endpoint.Send(new MTMessage { InputItemId = item.Id});
```

Note

- I have tried the various cases for the endpoint string.
- I do not want to capture the instance of IBus to call Send as that is not the 'closest' instance to the consumer, which according to the docs is important to consider.

Mass Transit document reference:  https://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#receive-endpoints

Thank you for any guidance with this,

Dylan

Answer (score 3):

As [explained in the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/producers.html#endpoint-address), there are short endpoint addresses which can be used. In your case:

```cs
await SendEndpointProvider.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("queue:process-input-item"));
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you.  I didn't see any reference for short names for In Memory in the documentation (https://masstransit-project.com/usage/producers.html#send), and i didn't consider that "queue" could apply to anything that emulates a queue.   Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: In-memory still has queues and exchanges/topics (it answers to both to ease testing). The in-memory fabric replicates the behavior of RabbitMQ exchanges and queues.